# Bar plot annotation showing to many numbers

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, bar-chart

When I add the annotation to my bar plot a lot of numbers are showing up in the bar itself. It is showing the correct number at the end of the bar plot but I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of the numbers inside the bar.

I thought maybe grouping the sales to the product would help but it is still showing the same thing. Unfortunately, I cannot give what the actual data is.

```
name = group_df['data1']
acw = group_df['data2']

#fig size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))

#horizontal bar
ax.barh(name, acw)

#Remove axes splines
for s in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
  ax.spines[s].set_visible(False)

#remove x, y ticks
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')

#add padding between axes and labels
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=5)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)

#add x, y gridlines
#ax.grid(visible = True, color ='black',
        #linestyle ='-.', linewidth = 0.5,
        #alpha = 0.2)

#show top values
ax.invert_yaxis()

#add annotation to bars
for i in ax.patches:
    plt.text(i.get_width()+0.2, i.get_y()+0.5, 
             str(round((i.get_width()), 2)),
             fontsize = 10, fontweight ='bold',
             color ='blue')

#add plot title
ax.set_title('Data',
             loc ='left', )

#show plot
plt.show()
```

[attached is how the bar graph looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu7yR.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data that reproduces this issue. Don't provide a lot of data, just enough data.

Comment: Maybe `group_df['data1']` contains the same names multiple times, and `ax.barh(...)` is plotting many bars on top of each other? Depending on what you want, you could try seaborn's `sns.barplot(x='data1', y='data2', orient='h', ax=ax)`. By default, that would show the average bar for each `y` value, together with error bars. Other options, such as summing or taking the largest, can be considered. To add labels to seaborn bars, `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])` can be used

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively straight forward to to this with standard boiler plate code.

i usually do something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

# Sample data
categories = ['Category A', 'Category B', 'Category C', 'Category D']
values = [10, 20, 15, 30]

# Create horizontal bar chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax: Axes
bars = ax.barh(categories, values)


# Add numbers at the end of each bar
for bar in bars:
    width = bar.get_width()
    ax.text(
        width, 
        bar.get_y() + bar.get_height()/2, 
        f'{width}', 
        ha='left', 
        va='center')

# Adjust the margins and layout
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.tight_layout()

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Which give this:
[image]

which you can modify for your own data.

Comment: You could simplify this using the `bar_label` method  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html

Comment: @RuthC,  thanks for pointing this out too !

Comment: Quite probably, OP is having repeated categories, so your approach with their data would lead to similar confusing overlapping labels. OP should clarify how their data look like, and how they want to cope with repeating categories. One approach could be `bars = ax.barh(range(len(categories)), values); ax.set_yticks(range(len(categories)), categories); ax.bar_label(bars)`